# SQL: Group by column with time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working on a little project on my own, its kinda a website monitor tool.
I have an agent running reading webpages, its reacting on website status codes, content checks and response time.

The table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `check_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content_string_used` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `content_check` enum('good','bad') NOT NULL,
  `http_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `namelookup_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `connect_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `pretransfer_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `starttransfer_time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What i am trying to do is to select all records for a specific check, example

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE  `check_id` = 173;
```

Now here is where it gets tricky and ill try to explain as good as possible.
The rows themselves have some columns that are important. Its the content_check and the http_code.

What i want to do is to group up all the rows with these two rows as separators and then select the start time from the first good one to the last good one.

Example...

```
SELECT id, check_id, content_check, http_code, time from data WHERE `check_id` = 173;
```

result

```
(15, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:43:11'),
(23, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:44:11'),
(35, 173,'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:45:11'),
(49, 173,'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:46:11'),
(67, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:47:11'),
(85, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:48:11'),
(105, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:49:11'),
(125, 173,'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:50:11'),
(145, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:51:11'),
(165, 173,'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:52:11');
```

id love a query that returns this to something like, basically sums up the good/bad with the time intervals as a delimiter of some sort.

```
(15, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:43:11', '2018-03-11 15:44:11'),
(35, 'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:45:11', '2018-03-11 15:46:11'),
(67, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:47:11', 2018-03-11 15:49:11),
(125, 'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:50:11', '2018-03-11 15:50:11'),
(145, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:51:11','2018-03-11 15:52:11'),
```

Please help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no proper grouping criteria for bad and good

Answer (score 0):

One trick that will work for something like this is to use a pair of variables to keep track of the most recent record's `check_id` and `http_code`, plus a third variable to represent a group number whose value is incremented only on records whose `check_id` or `http_code` differ from those of the preceding record. For instance, given the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `check_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `content_check` enum('good','bad') NOT NULL,
    `http_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into `data`
    (`id`, `check_id`, `content_check`, `http_code`, `time`)
values
    (15, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:43:11'),
    (23, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:44:11'),
    (35, 173, 'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:45:11'),
    (49, 173, 'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:46:11'),
    (67, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:47:11'),
    (85, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:48:11'),
    (105, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:49:11'),
    (125, 173, 'good', 0, '2018-03-11 15:50:11'),
    (145, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:51:11'),
    (165, 173, 'bad', 0, '2018-03-11 15:52:11');

set @lastContentCheck = '';
set @lastHttpCode = '';
```

I can write the following query that will assign the group numbers as described above:

```
select
    `id`,
    `check_id`,
    @groupNumber :=
        case
            when @lastContentCheck = `content_check` and @lastHttpCode = `http_code` then @groupNumber
            else @groupNumber + 1
        end as `GroupNumber`,
    @lastContentCheck := `content_check` as `content_check`,
    @lastHttpCode := `http_code` as `http_code`,
    `time`
from
    `data`,
    (select @groupNumber := 0) as `gn`
where
    `check_id` = 173
order by
    `time`
```

The output of this query is:

```
id   check_id  GroupNumber  content_check  http_code  time
15   173       1            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:43:11
23   173       1            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:44:11
35   173       2            good           0          2018-03-11 15:45:11
49   173       2            good           0          2018-03-11 15:46:11
67   173       3            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:47:11
85   173       3            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:48:11
105  173       3            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:49:11
125  173       4            good           0          2018-03-11 15:50:11
145  173       5            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:51:11
165  173       5            bad            0          2018-03-11 15:52:11
```

At this point you can get the result set you want by simply wrapping another query around the one above that groups its data by the `GroupNumber`. So the whole thing would look like this:

```
select
    min(`id`) as `id`,
    `check_id`,
    `content_check`,
    `http_code`,
    min(`time`) as `EarliestTime`,
    max(`time`) as `LatestTime`
from
    (
        select
            `id`,
            `check_id`,
            @groupNumber :=
                case
                    when @lastContentCheck = `content_check` and @lastHttpCode = `http_code` then @groupNumber
                    else @groupNumber + 1
                end as `GroupNumber`,
            @lastContentCheck := `content_check` as `content_check`,
            @lastHttpCode := `http_code` as `http_code`,
            `time`
        from
            `data`,
            (select @groupNumber := 0) as `gn`
        where
            `check_id` = 173
        order by
            `time`
    ) as `GroupedData`
group by
    `check_id`,
    `GroupNumber`,
    `content_check`,
    `http_code`
order by
    `GroupNumber`;
```

And the result is as you wanted:

```
id   check_id  content_check  http_code  EarliestTime         LatestTime
15   173       bad            0          2018-03-11 15:43:11  2018-03-11 15:44:11
35   173       good           0          2018-03-11 15:45:11  2018-03-11 15:46:11
67   173       bad            0          2018-03-11 15:47:11  2018-03-11 15:49:11
125  173       good           0          2018-03-11 15:50:11  2018-03-11 15:50:11
145  173       bad            0          2018-03-11 15:51:11  2018-03-11 15:52:11
```

[Demo on sqltest.net](https://sqltest.net/#175273)